# multiple batch update in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, codeigniter

i have a codeigniter website where user can select multiple data using checkbox and edit those at once, all that is working fine, multiple row cn be selected, they are displayed at once, but after i submit the form, its not getting saved, i did the following :

```html
<label for="inputEmail4">Product Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" value="<?=$valad->name?>" required>
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" value="<?=$valad->id?>" required>

<label for="inputEmail4">SKU</label>
<input type="text" name="sku[]" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" value="<?=$valad->sku?>" required>
```

```html
if(isset($_POST['editinventoryproducts']))
{
  $id=$this->input->post('id');
$name=$this->input->post('name');
$sku=$this->input->post('sku');
$this->excel_import_model->editinventoryproductsm($id,$name,$sku);
$this->session->set_flashdata("Successade","Product Edited Successfully !");
redirect('inventoryproducts' , 'refresh');
}
```

and finally model:

```html
public function editinventoryproductsm($id,$name,$sku) {
$this->db->where_in('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('inventoryproducts', array('name' => $name, 'sku' => $sku));
        return true;
}
```

i am getting the following database error:

```html
Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

UPDATE `inventoryproducts` SET `name` = Array, `sku` = Array WHERE `id` IN('16', '17')
```

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your UI, that might give us the idea. Your HTML does not look to work as you are saying

Comment: bro, the issue is with the insertion to the database, the html is fine, i am using foreach to display multiple edit form, its working fine, the data is also passed to the controller on button click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you have correct array data in the model, if so, then this can easily be done by `update_batch`.

First you need to create the array properly, then the single line of `$this->db->update_batch` is enough to do your job:

```
public function editinventoryproductsm($id,$name,$sku) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($id as $a){
        $data[$i] = array('id' => $id[$i], 'name' => $name[$i],'sku' => $sku[$i]);
        $i++;
    }

    $this->db->update_batch('inventoryproducts', $data, 'id');
    return true;
}
```

From the CI Documentation : The first parameter will contain the table name, the second is an associative array of values, the third parameter is the where key.